# Rotate circle around center point (D3)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a circle element whose `cx` and `cy` attributes I'm trying to use to rotate the circle around a center point (of a circle). I'm using D3's `d3.behavior.drag` to this. I'm using the new points given by `d3.event.x` and `d3.event.y` to calculate the delta between these points and the initial points. From other, similar posts, I've gathered that using JavaScript's arctangent method is the way to calculate the circle's new position:

```
var rad = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
```

However, when I click the circle to drag, **it seems to jump 180 degrees on x mouse movement, and moves much to quickly on y mouse movement**. After this, it seems to correctly respond to mouse behavior. I can't figure out why the circle is jumping to a different point on the arc...

Here is the relevant code, seen fully in a working [codepen](http://codepen.io/himmel/pen/LpGJeP):

```
g.append('circle')
    .attr({
        class: 'rotatable',
        r: 20,
        cx: r * Math.cos(0),
        cy: r * Math.sin(0),
    })
    .call(drag);

// store initial points
var xInit = d3.select('.rotatable').attr('cx');
var yInit = d3.select('.rotatable').attr('cy');

function drag() {
    // calculate delta for mouse coordinates
    var deltaX = d3.event.x - xInit;
    var deltaY = d3.event.y - yInit;

    var rad = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);

    d3.select(this)
        .attr({
            cx: r * Math.cos(rad),
            cy: r * Math.sin(rad)
        });

}
```

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `xInit` and `yInit`?  If you remove them, it seems to work: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qObJYr?editors=001

Comment: Yes, it does. I was trying to use the initial placement to calculate the total amount moved. I guess that got in the way of the basic functionality.